C program for calculating pi using pthread doesn't give a correct approximation
Below is some code I made that uses pthreads that calculates an approximation of pi.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

long num_terms;
double sum = 0.0;
pthread_mutex_t sum_lock;

void* calculate_pi(void* r) {
        long rank = (long) r;
        double factor;
        long n = num_terms / rank;
        long first = n * rank;
        long last = first + n;

        if (first % 2 == 0) {
                factor = 1.0;
        } else {
                factor = -1.0;
        }

        for (long i = first; i < last; i++, factor = -factor) {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&sum_lock);
                sum += factor / (2 * i + 1);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&sum_lock);
        }

        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        if (argc != 3) {
                printf("Error: must have exactly 3 arguments.\n");
                return 1;
        }

        long num_threads = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        num_terms = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);

        pthread_t* threads = malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));
        pthread_mutex_init(&sum_lock, NULL);

        for (long i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
                pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calculate_pi, (void*) i + 1);
        }

        for (long i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
                pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        }

        sum = sum * 4.0;

        printf("Estimated value of pi: %f\n", sum);

        pthread_mutex_destroy(&sum_lock);
        free(threads);

        return 0;
}

Normally, when I run this program with the sample arguments 4 and 1000000, it's supposed to print out this:

Estimated value of pi: 3.141593

But instead, it prints out this, which isn't even close to the value of pi:

Estimated value of pi: -0.000001

Can you figure out what's wrong?

When you used a debugger, what was the first thing the program did that you didn't expect?

Are you able to calculate π without using threads?

Does it work when you call calculate_pi directly, not via pthread_create? Does it work with one thread? When you add code to each thread to print the contribution to sum that it calculates, are the printed values what you expect?

Do not smuggle arguments into a thread by converting an integer to a pointer. Do it the way it was intended: Pass a pointer to the argument. The argument should be a separate object (for example, a separate array element) for each thread.

Your calculations of n, first, and last are wrong. Redo them from scratch. You may need to pass more than one number to calculate_pi. Do that with a structure containing multiple members. Remember, each structure passed to a thread will need to be a separate structure from that passed to any other thread, so create an array of structures.

Presumably you hope that you can get the same level of accuracy in half the time by doubling the thread count (assuming you have enough free cores). But you are updating a global sum inside your loop, protecting it with a mutex. It's good to protect the summation with the mutex, but the threads will spend so much time in contention on the mutex that it will probably be slower than a single thread. You need to design the code so that each thread can do a LOT of work locally before updating the global.

(void*) i + 1 is equivalent to ((void*) i) + 1, which has undefined behavior -- pointer arithmetic is defined only for pointers to complete types, which void is not.  It would be better written (void*) (i + 1).  However, if your compiler accepts the original code at all then it is probably giving you behavior consistent with that anyway, so this is not likely to be the source of your discrepancy.

One other thing in addition to the thread glitches. Numerically you will get a better answer by summing from the smallest term to the largest one and you can avoid having excessive cancellation by summing  adjacent alternating terms algebraically. 1/(2*i+1)-1/(2*i+3) == 2/((2*i+1)*(2*i+3). It also halves the number of divides.  There are many much better ways to compute pi accurately. You have chosen to evaluate one of the least convergent series known for pi.

You could probably increase the speed a lot by using a local sum in each thread and only update the global sum after the loop. With this you don't need to wait for the mutex in each iteration of the loop.
